# Authentication API - How can I use a changing Salt client side?

Tags: javascript, java

So, let's say I have an authentication Server and a Client that sends a Request with credentials.

My Problem is that when I use a generated Salt, the Server doesn't know about that changed Salt e.g. The Client generates a new Salt, sends the credentials hashed with the new Salt to the Server, which doesn't know the new Salt, because in the Database with the stored Password there's still the hashed Password with the old Salt. If i implement the Salt server-side it's useless because the Password will still be sent Hashed without the Salt to the server.

How can i add the changing salt client side and let the Server / Database know about the changed Salt without hard coding any passwords / keys / etc...

Authentication:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// create a MySQL connection to xx.xx.xx.xx
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', user: 'xxxx', password: 'XXXXXXXXX', database: 'customers'
});

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// define the API endpoint
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // execute the query
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM customers.Unfallmeldung WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?', [username, password], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({error});
    }


    if (results.length > 0) {
      let response = [results[0].Company, results[0].Access, results[0].Databases];
      return res.status(200).json({message: response});
    }

    return res.status(401).json({message: 'Invalid credentials'});
  });
});

// start the server
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started on port 3000'));
```

Client:

```
package com.pichlmayr.unfallmeldung;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class APIClient {
    private static final String API_URL = "https://xx.xx/login";

    public static String[][] authenticate(String username, String password) {

        try {
            // create a connection to the API endpoint
            URL url = new URL(API_URL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //hash password
            password = HashPassword.encrypt(password);
            // create the request body
            String requestBody = "{\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}";

            // send the request
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(requestBody.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            // read the response
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String response = br.readLine();
            br.close();


            
            if(response.contains("Error: ") || response.contains("Invalid credentials")) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + response);
                return null;
            }

            response = response.replace("\"", "");
            response = response.replace("[", "");
            response = response.replace("]", "");
            response = response.replace("{", "");
            response = response.replace("}", "");
            
            response = response.substring(8);
            
            String[] responseArray = response.split(",");
            String[] company = new String[]{responseArray[0]};
            String[] access = new String[]{responseArray[1]};
            String [] databases = new String[responseArray.length-2];
            System.arraycopy(responseArray, 2, databases, 0, responseArray.length - 2);

            return new String[][]{company, access, databases};
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hash Method:

```
package com.pichlmayr.unfallmeldung;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HashPassword {
    public static String encrypt(String passwordToHash) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String salt = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
        return (get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt));
    }

    private static String get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(String passwordToHash, String salt) {
        String generatedPassword = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            md.update(salt.getBytes());
            byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte aByte : bytes) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((aByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            generatedPassword = sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return generatedPassword;
    }

    // Add salt
    /*  private static String getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt.toString();
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Why are you hashing the password on the client side? The hashed password you are sending becomes the actual password and now looks to be stored in plaintext.

Comment: so in the database i have stored the hashed password - client hashes it - sends it to server - server checks if hashes match.

Well if i just send the password as plain text to the server, wouldn't that be unsafe as anyone listening to network traffic can see that?

Comment: Your transport should protect the password (e.g. TLS). See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side

Answer (score 0):

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// generate a salt and hash the password
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

// compare the hashed password with the stored hash
const isMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, storedHash);
```

Comment: yeah, but that way the salt is still on the server side, so I am still sending the Password to the Server without the Salt, but I want to add a random salt client side.